# Post-1980 to Pre-2017, medieval-style fantasy book with illiterate female protagonist

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, medieval

This was a library book I read years ago, which I want to find in hopes it's a series.

The main protagonist is a simple farm/village girl who ends up going to a medieval style city to work as a servant. She is illiterate and part of the book is about her learning to read in secret from her master, who is the second point of view.

His parts of the story involve flashbacks to an ancient hidden magical cult-slash-academy. I remember a scene involving him and other students having to use magic to conjure their food and being forced to starve if they couldn't.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: i feel pretty dumb, i managed to find a much older post for the same book so now i have the title ( skin hunger )

Comment: You definitely shouldn't feel dumb, that happens to all of us.  You can self-answer your question, or just nominate to close it as duplicate.  The latter is less work, but the former will earn you more points. :)

Comment: For the record, dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125270/23243, but I'll wait for a day to cast a close vote until you get a chance to write your answer.